# it possible to highlight the node found by the search - Orgchart

Tags: orgchart

Is it possible to highlight the node found by the search in order to just display the animated effect on it?
Select the node found to fetch an access point for the node and display an effect on it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
chart.center(nodeId);
```

or

```
chart.ripple(nodeId);
```

Here is an example:

```js
var chart = new OrgChart(document.getElementById("tree"), {
            nodeBinding: {
                field_0: "name",
                field_1: "id"
            },
            nodes: [
                { id: 1, name: "Amber McKenzie" },
                { id: 2, pid: 1, name: "Ava Field" },
                { id: 3, pid: 1, name: "Peter Stevens" }
            ]
        });
        
document.getElementById("center").addEventListener("click", function(){
  chart.center(3);
});

document.getElementById("ripple").addEventListener("click", function(){
  chart.ripple(3);
});
```

```css
html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
#tree{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

#center{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 140px;
  z-index: 5000;
}

#ripple{
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  right: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 140px;
  z-index: 5000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://balkangraph.com/js/latest/OrgChart.js"></script>
<button id="center">center(3)</button>
<button id="ripple">ripple(3)</button>
<div id="tree"/>
```